# Background Image Being Covered by Something Issue

Tags: css, image, background

The background image I have in a div on my website shows up in the inspect element and the background image is correctly pathed in css but it is covered up by something in my code ,and I can't seem to find it.If anyone can look at my code and see what the problem is,it would be greatly appreciated.

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

body,html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

body {
    text-decoration:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#000;
}

.wallpaper {
    background-image: url('/../images/wallpaper.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% auto;
    background-position:center top;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
}

.nav {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:1;
}

.nav ul {
    text-align:center;
    float:right;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-right:50px;
}

.nav ul li {
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
}


.nav ul li a {
    color:#fff;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding:0 10px 7px 10px;
    font-family: "Playfair Display";
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="wallpaper">
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a>Home</a></li>
        <li><a>About</a></li>
        <li><a>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: covered up by something is what? can you share the webpage view?

Comment: If your link an image then it works fine but for some reason it doesn't work from the path..

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

Change HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a>Home</a></li>
        <li><a>About</a></li>
        <li><a>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="wallpaper">
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Change CSS:

```
.wallpaper {
    background-image: url('http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/5718897981_10faa45ac3_b-640x624.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% auto;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/PRW69/r258vvvm/

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You need to double-check the path - that's where the issue is.  If you share your folder structure, maybe we could help point out the error.